# TestNG - Why does testNG reporter not print out else statements?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to check whether the submit button on my login form is pressed when the correct details are put in. I also want to check when the login details fail to print a message to the NGreporter that the login failed. My code is below:

```
WebElement  login = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_1_label"));

Assert.assertTrue(login.isDisplayed());

if(login.isDisplayed()){
  login.click();
  Reporter.log("Login Form Submitted  | ");
} else { 
  Reporter.log("Login Failed  | ");
}
```

When the correct details are entered it will print Login form Submitted to the reporter, however, when it fails it does not print Login Failed to the reporter.

Maybe I am using isDisplayed wrongly for checking weather a submit was successful or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the else block never executes is because `Assert.assertTrue(...)` throws an AssertionError when `login.isDisplayed()` is false.  As a result, the if-else block is never reached when `login.isDisplayed()` is false, only when it is true (in which case only the if portion is executed).

The quickest way to achieve what you want is to move the assertion line *below* the if-else block, like so:

```
WebElement  login = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_1_label"));

if(login.isDisplayed()){
  login.click();
  Reporter.log("Login Form Submitted  | ");
} else { 
  Reporter.log("Login Failed  | ");
}

Assert.assertTrue(login.isDisplayed());
```

And if you want to avoid making asserting twice that `login.isDisplayed()` returns true then you can use `Assert.fail()` inside your else block:

```
WebElement  login = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_1_label"));

if(login.isDisplayed()){
    login.click();
    Reporter.log("Login Form Submitted  | ");
} else {
    Reporter.log("Login Failed  | ");
    Assert.fail("Login was not displayed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciation the help.

Comment: I'm really hoping you will accept this answer so that I can earn the Speedy Delivery hat before Winter Bash 2015 is over.